# Ways to prevent overheating on XBOX 360?

Tags: xbox-360

My XBOX 360 sometimes freezes because it gets overheated. Mainly because I don't have a lot of ventilation in my room.

So I was thinking about buying a fan to cool it down. After searching a little on Amazon I found a couple of them, but in the reviews people said that these fans didn't help at all, their problem only got worse.

Any sugestion on how I can cool down the XBOX without having to put a fan in front of the console?

Comment: Are you sure it's due to heat? What model XBox do you have?

Comment: Model would help, and if there are specific games it's locking up on, that would be nice to know too.

Comment: Related [question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5647/tips-on-preventing-red-ring-of-death)

Comment: Xbox 360 4GB S Console (Black)

Comment: I'm surprised no one mentioned cleaning it out.  Overheating typically occurs due to buildup of dust on the heatsinks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Assuming it is overheating, and before spending money on an external device, see if the tips [Microsoft provides about placement of your Xbox](http://support.xbox.com/en-us/pages/xbox-360/troubleshoot/hardware/best-location-xbox-360.aspx) help:

> - Put the console in an open area with lots of ventilation. Do not put the console in an enclosed space.
> - Do not stack other electronic devices on top of, underneath, or against the sides of your console.
> - Make sure the console and its power supply are on a hard, steady surface. Do not put the console on anything soft (such as a bed, sofa, or rug).
> - Position the console away from heat sources, such as ventilation openings on televisions and electronic devices. Also, keep the console away from heating vents and direct sunlight.
> - Position the console away from high-vibrating sources, such as low frequency speakers, subwoofers, etc.

And whatever you do, absolutely do not place your Xbox next to a picture of Clippy:

[image: Clippy the Xbox Killer]

Comment: Thanks, the XBOX its not close to a picture of Clippy. lol

Comment: The Xbox will go the way of Clippy if this ever happens.

Answer (score 2):

I really recommend to get some ventilation room for the xbox. Setting up internal fan is hard and external fan may not help that much. And as you said, it can make the problem worse.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with my Xbox. After playing a game after about 15 minutes it will overheat. I have tried putting a box fan next to the Xbox but doing that makes me nervous that that might make it worse. I have tried all of the techniques but I think that the main problem might be that the fan in the Xbox might be too dusty. I would suggest that maybe you should buy a dust gun or a can of pressurized air to try to shoot all of the dust and crap out of your Xbox. The dust could be the reason that your Xbox doesn't get any ventilation.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a little difficult to get a hold of now but [Lian Li released a replacement case for the 360](http://www.lian-li.com/en/dt_portfolio/pc-xb01/) (this might not work with the new slim model parts so some research will be required there). But it looks like there is a lot more space inside the case and significantly better airflow as a result. Give it a look.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try laying it down. This way the air can come from both sides and you can try putting something cold near places that air comes in to the XBox.

Answer (score -1):

I stripped off most of the casing apart from the front, back and bottom and now it rarely overheats

Answer (score -1):

get a new fan in the Xbox,install it into the Xbox and if that doesn't help,try taking it to GameStop and put it in the hands of the professionals

Comment: Welcome to [Gaming.SE].  For tips on writing great answers, please see the related [Help section](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).  As an example, if a 5-year-old question already has an accepted answer, consider whether your suggestion is as good or as likely to help the original poster as the accepted one.

Answer (score -3):

Put water in a ziplock baggie put that baggie in another one and make sure their locked then set it face up oh and add ice to make it cold if ur nervous put a paper towel under it this only works when the xbox is laying down